# Enum with flag and Bitwise operation

Tags: c#, enums, flags

I have a senario and I am using following enum for the same

```
[Flags]
enum State
{
    None = 0x00,
    Added = 0x01,
    Edited = 0x02,
    Commented = 0x04,
    Uncommented = 0x8,
    Reordered = 0x16
}
```

I wanted to get result like this

if Added  result will be

> Added

if then Edited result will be

> Added, Edited

if then Reordered will be

> Added, Edited, Reordered

if then Commented will be

> Added, Edited, Reordered, Commented

if then Uncommented will be

> Added, Edited, Reordered, Commented , Uncommented

if then Commented will be

> Added, Edited, Reordered, Commented , Uncommented , Commented

and so on.

Please advice whether I can do the same using any `Bitwise` operation.

Comment: It sounds like you don't really want bitwise flags, if you can't actually set each part separately...

Comment: you can't store the same flag value multiple times in one variable, you will need to make a `List<State>` and then you can drop the flag semantics

Comment: I like the values, especially 0x16 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two of your requirements make it impossible to use a bitwise flags enum for this purpose.

- There is no way to represent the order in which bits were set.
- There is no way to represent a bit being set more that once.

All of these actions are indistinguishable when using a bitwise flag enum:

```
Added, Edited, Reordered
Added, Reordered, Edited
Added, Edited, Reordered, Edited
```

They are all represented as `Added | Edited | Reordered`.

As mentioned in comments, you should instead use a `List<State>` to represent this data.

Comment: And, as alluded to in the comments, `Reordered` is deceptive in this flags enum since it always sets the bits for `Edited` and `Commented` (since using hex notation, the next single bit value should be `0x10`, not `0x16`)